# EC2 instance connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which until last week I could connect through ssh using a key fine. Since then, I can not connect on it anymore. Also, ping do not respond. But, I can still access my website that runs on that instance. To the best of my knowledge, I havent applied any change on security settings that could be blocking it. Is there any suggestions on what could going on?

Comment: My guess is it doesn't have an elastic IP and restarted so it's been assigned a new IP address. I know it doesn't explain how you can still your website but it may be because of other things and need more information. The initial step I'd recommend would be login to AWS console, select your instance and check what it says on Public IP and Elastic IP fields in the properties pane

Comment: try ssh with `-vvv` flag and check the output

Comment: Did you change *your* IP address, so the security group won't allow you inbound access? (eg Your ISP could have assigned a new IP address to a home router.) What are your Security Group settings?